# Unexpected result when using atoi() on content of file, read char by char

Tags: c, file, atoi

I have a text file in which there are only numbers (0, 1, 2 & 3) and I want to process the data to know how many times each number appears.

The following program works with small text file (<100 numbers) but with bigger files (I need to process in the end several thousands of data) the program reads numbers that are not in the text file.

Here's my code :

```
FILE *file;
char c;
int nb;
int th0 = 0, th1 = 0, th2 = 0, th3 = 0;

file = fopen("../data", "r");

if (file == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR FILE: %s", strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

while (1) {
    if (fscanf(file, "%c", &c) == EOF)
        break;

    nb = atoi(&c);

    printf("%d", nb);

    switch (nb) {
      case 0:
        th0++;
        break;

      case 1:
        th1++;
        break;

      case 2:
        th2++;
        break;

      case 3:
        th3++;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT, the input text with the output :

Data file (181 numbers):

`001110120101010102012012021201021202102012012012012010210210210120120230103120130230123201320310231023102302301231203213210131032103210230120320310320213202301320123120312302321023`

Output:
[The end of the reading is not what is in the data file and count 156 numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp4ZY.png)

Comment: Numbers (inlcuding e.g. 100) or only single digit numbers ?

Comment: There are single digit, only 0, 1, 2 or 3

Comment: Reading a character at a time isn't very efficient - you'll probably find it works better if you read in a chunk and process that

Comment: Please show sample input. How are the digits separated?

Comment: Or to ask differently, does the file contain anything but repetitions of those four digits? Space, tab, colon, newline, carriage return ...

Comment: No there's no other character than these 4 numbers.

Comment: I have to process it char by char because the data file is 1 line with all the data. So I won't have a buffer large enough to process everything

Comment: Show your input and your error. Please try to make it as much of a [MCVE] as possible. Please also close your files when you're done with them.

Comment: @JoM line length won't matter - use `fgets` and it will read in at most the amount you specify or up to the end of the line.

Comment: Don't use atoi (family) ever. Use strtol (family) instead. They are 100% equivalent except strto... has proper error handling and support more bases than decimal.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: Echoing Lundin, use `strtol` family functions instead and don't ignore its error-handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `atoi` expects a string and you're calling it like this:

```
nb = atoi(&c);
```

with `c` being just a `char`. Sometimes that might work, but you're basically hitting undefined behaviour as you can't guarantee that the memory after `c` is empty.

Instead you want to calculate `nb` differently.

```
nb = c - '0';
```

This relies on the fact that in the ASCII table, the numbers 0 to 9 are in a block together. Subtracting the value of '0' from `c` will get you the numerical value of that character...assuming it is a digit.

And just to ensure it is a digit you should wrap this `if` statement around your code

```
if(isdigit(c)) // Check if c is a digit
    {
    nb = c - '0';

    switch(nb) {
        case 0: th0++;
        break;
    // rest of switch goes here....
         }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks, everything is working with this way of converting!

Comment: *This relies on the fact that in the ASCII table, the digits `0` to `9` are in a block together.* This is actually guaranteed by the C Standard for all supported encodings, not just ASCII

Answer (score 3):

Looking at

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi

I see

> Parameters
>   str -   pointer to the null-terminated byte string to be interpreted

But with

```
char c;
/* ... */
nb = atoi(&c);
```

you are using a pointer to a single `char`, which is followed by who-knows-what.
For anything which happens to not be a `'\0'` you will get a result from `atoi()` which is

a) based on access beyond the intended variable
b) for following digits, is a two-digit number or higher

The first option means that your code needs fixing.
The second option can explain any number > 9.

Comment: Thanks! I changed my way of converting as Chris suggested. And all is working

Answer (score 0):

You call `atoi` with a pointer to `char` that does not point to a proper C string, hence your code has undefined behavior and may seem to work as expected sometimes and misbehave at other times...

Since you are dealing with digits, you could compute the value represented by the digit with a simple subtraction `c - '0'`.

You could also simplify the code with an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    int c, i;
    int count[10] = { 0 };

    file = fopen("../data", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR FILE: %s", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            count[c - '0']++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    printf("counts:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, count[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```